# View not updating properly with asynchronous queries? (MVVM, C#, WPF, NPGSQL)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, npgsql

I have a very odd problem. Take the code below.I'm using NPGSQL to connect with a postgresql database. I simplified the code so that i could explain this problem easier.

XAML

```
....
<TextBox x:Name="Countrytext" Text="{Binding Address.Country,
 Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource EmployeeViewModel}}" 
Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  MinHeight="10"  Height="20"/>
....
```

WPF C#

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name, surname FROM employee WHERE bsn = " + Employee.Bsn;
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    Address.Country = "Something";
  }
}

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT country, postal_code FROM lives_at WHERE bsn = " + Employee.Bsn;
  using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader.Read())
    {                            
      Address.Country = "SomethingElse";
    }
   }
```

EDIT:
Maybe the code of the Address model can add something to this question

```
  public class Address : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string country;
    public string Country
    {
        get { return country; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("country");
            country = value;

        }
    }

    private string postalCode;
    public string PostalCode
    {
        get { return postalCode; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("postalCode");
            postalCode = value;

        }
    }

    private string street;
    public string Street
    {
        get { return street; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("street");
            country = value;
        }
    }

    private string number;
    public string Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("number");
            number = value;
        }
    }

    public Address()
    {

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

I'm using WPF. My view is bound the the viewmodel which contains this code. When i execute the code, the field in my viewmodel that is bound to Address.Country is set to "Something" instead of "SomethingElse". This confuses me because when i debug the program, Address.Country is actually set to "SomethingElse". Deleting 'Address.Country = "Something" Does not help. Why does this happen?

Comment: How are you notifying the view that the property has been updated?  Also, this code belongs in the model or the data access layer, not the view model.

Comment: Does the `Address` (its class) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and does changing the `Country` property actually raise the `PropertyChanged` event? Both of these things are required for "active" data-binding to work.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Address implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The event is raised when Country is changed. The first query executes properly and country is changed. Yet for some reason the second query causes problems. Even though it executes perfectly (Since can see Address.Country being changed into "SomethingElse").

Comment: @rory.ap Really? I thought the model contains the reusable code. The classes that implement INPC. Than i have a reference to this model and others in the viewModel that can access the data. I am very new to the subject so i would definitely appreciate an explanation :)

Comment: @Stephen -- The view model should only contain code that's related to presentation logic.  Querying the database is *definitely* not related to presentation logic; that's a deeper concern that belongs in the model.  The model is simply a representation of your domain and the business logic that is the essence of your application, and that's where repository access code should go.

Comment: @rory.ap Should i use the Repository Pattern to solve this issue?

Comment: @Stephen -- *How* you access the repository is not germane to your issue.  Your main question is: why isn't my view updating, and the reason, as I alluded to before and Bradley Uffner directly indicated, is probably that you aren't notifying the view that the view model property (Country) has changed.  I'm also pointing out, as a secondary consideration, that your view model contains concerns (i.e. data access) that belong in your model.  Sure, you can use the repository pattern or whatever else, but it's not relevant to your question.

Comment: The only other oddity I see, is that you are binding to `Address` properties through a `StaticResource`.  I've never seen "normal" data-binding done that way, and I'm not sure if it could have strange side effects under some condition.  Is there any technical reason you are doing it this way?  If not, I would recommend using the more standard binding method of setting the `DataContext` (of the view) and using the `{Binding Path=SomeProperty}` syntax.

Comment: @rory.ap Yes, i was aware of that. I was just wondering how i would seperate the data access from the View Model.

As for the issue, the country actually does update. So the view is being notified. It just updates to "something" and not "SomethingElse" even though the debugger shows me that the value of Address.Country is "somethingElse". 

What could i provide that would make this issue more clear?

Comment: @BradleyUffner That's what the tutorial told me. I could do: "DataContext = EmployeViewModel; in the code behind but because i want complete seperation i'd rather do it in XAML using page.resource / staticresource. I changed. Now it doesn't update at all. Which is some different behavior, we might be on to something.

Comment: Spun up a demo and the bloody binding doesn't care about casing.  Derp.

Comment: You do realize that you are notifying the view **before** you update the value. Code will work no problem, this is a logical error, `OnPropertyChanged` should be after `property = value;`. Live long and prosper